# How to debug a Raku program

Tags: raku, rakudo

I looked at the documentation, but I didn't quite understand how to debug. I use the raku-debug command, but it reports an error:

> Could not find Debugger::UI::CommandLine.

When I tried to search on zef, I didn't find any results.

Does Raku have a tuning tool similar to gdb, just like Python or JavaScript debugging tools? How am I supposed to debug a Raku program?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Migrating solution from the comments:</sub>

> There's this page in the docs (https://docs.raku.org/programs/01-debugging). It says that to run the `raku-debug-m` command, you must first install `Debugger::UI::CommandLine`, which comes bundled with Rakudo Star. However going to the debugger's repo (https://github.com/jnthn/rakudo-debugger), it states it's been superseded by MoarVM Remote Debug which has both a GUI (through [the Comma IDE](https://commaide.com/)) and a CLI.
>
> – [uzluisf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824322/uzluisf) [Jul 23 at 22:23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76749240/how-to-debug-a-raku-program#comment135309467_76749240)

> so, long story short: download Comma; it comes with debugging facilities, breakpoints, and all you need to debug a program. Since it's based on IntelliJ Idea, it's similar to PyCharm or WebStorm, so you're in familiar territory
>
> – [jjmerelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891440/jjmerelo) [Jul 24 at 7:53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76749240/how-to-debug-a-raku-program#comment135312579_76749240)